# Clear url in adressbar with location.hash

Tags: javascript, html

How do i use `location.hash` to change url from:

`localhost:8080/login.php`
to
`localhost:8080`

i have tried to to this 
`body onload="location.hash = '1'`

Comment: `location.hash` is what comes after the `#` sign. It refers generally to in-page anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use location.href to change the url, ie `location.href = 'http://localhost:8080'`